# How to draw a boxplot with whiskers correctly?

Tags: graphing-functions, descriptive-statistics

I want to draw a boxplot with whiskers where a lower bound is equal to $Q1 - 1.5 IQR$ and an upper bound is equal to $Q3 + 1.5 IQR$, where $Q1$ is a lower quantile, $Q3$ is an upper quantile and $IQR$ ia an interquantile range.

My observations are positive, but the value $Q1 - 1.5 IQR$ is below $0$.
My question is:

Where should I put a lower bound of whiskers on a boxplot: in the point $Q1 - 1.5 IQR$ (which is negative) or in the point equal to $0$, because all my observations are positive?

Comment: What do you by mean lower bound? The $ 1.5 \times IQR$ is a rule of thumb to highlight potential outliers.

Comment: I suggest using the lowest data value if none are outliers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whiskers should extend to the most extreme *data* points satisfying the criterion that they lie within $Q1-1.5IQR$ and $Q3+1.5IQR$ from the respective box edges.

e.g. see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/boxplot.html) and read about 'range'

Comment: Thank you for your response.